# ScaleBreakStyle with FSharpChart 0.60

Tags: charts, f#, data-visualization, fsharpchart, f#-charting

I'm trying to make a chart with [FSharpChart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/FSharpChart-b59073f5) that has a scale break in it.  I found an [example for asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axisscalebreakstyle.collapsiblespacethreshold.aspx) that I have tried to rewrite for F#.  However, the resulting chart does not have any scale break but has normal y-axis.  Here is my code:

```
#r @"libs\MSDN.FSharpChart.dll.0.60\lib\MSDN.FSharpChart.dll"
#r @"System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization"

open MSDN.FSharp.Charting
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

let c = [2;4;40000;3] |> FSharpChart.Line

c.Area.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled <- true
c.Area.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.CollapsibleSpaceThreshold <- 25
c.Area.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth <- 2
c.Area.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.StartFromZero <- StartFromZero.Auto
c.Area.AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing <- 2.0

FSharpChart.Create c
```

Thanks for any help!  This doesn't work if you run it from the command line - must be in fsi (so that it keeps running).

Comment: when you say you cannot get it to work can you be more specific

Comment: @JohnPalmer Sorry, I meant that the chart does not have the scale break that it should.  I edited the original post to reflect this clarification.

Comment: I would guess this is because FSharpChart sets a number of properties that are incompatible with the ScaleBreak feature, as summed up in the Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455709.aspx